# How to find a substring in a string - by specifying the beginning and end of it?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, substring

I want to get some data from a website.

My program currently uses urllib.request to read the entire html document.
Because the website changes, the data of the HTML file is different each time I run the program.

Some data remains the same - the start and the end point of a < script >.

I want to tell python what the start and end of the substring are supposed to be.

I've googled this, but have only found a way that requires you to know the substring in advance to look for it - for example:

```
str1.find(str2)
```

Here is a snippet of my program:

```
import urllib.request

def get_html():
with urllib.request.urlopen("http://website.com/dynamic_page") as response:
    html = response.read()
    return html

print(get_html())
```

This prints a long string, but I just need to get a part of it, otherwise my other function looks for strings in the whole document instead of just a small part:

```
def search_custom(string):

    html = get_html()
    string_var = string
    string_var = string_var.encode('utf-8')

    string_count = html.count(string_var)
    print(string_count)

    return string_count
```

Comment: What do you want exactly? remove `<script>..</script>` of your html string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your page data changes but the structure is going to be the same. Why not use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) and scrape the particular div/script tag?

An example

`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
message = soup.find("script")
```

This will get you the very first script tag. You might not want the first tag. There are many other way to scrape. You can look at the [docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like:

```
start = str1.find("<script>")
if start > -1:
    end = str1[start:].find("</script>")
    if end > -1:
        data = str1[start + 8:start + end]
```